# Themes : Navigation and status bars on Lollipop

Tags: sony

I'm really facing a big problem when it's about making themes for Xperia phones 
which got Android Lollipop.

First of all I'm making themes with Theme creator Beta from Sony and the problem is that this bar doesn't change:

[image]

It's the same thing with other themes that I downloaded from Google Play Store 
 Otherwise It changes in other themes like Little big planet theme from Sony that is updated yesterday to make this appear:

[image]

We find this:

[image]

This is where we can find a lot of modifications in lollipop Android Version.

How can I do this with any possible way?

Remark: I Have an Xperia Z3 device 
- I Create themes with Theme Creator BETA from Sony.

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop isn't supported as of yet with the Theme Creator tool.

*'Some of you have been asking for Android 5.0 (Lollipop) support, and we can assure you that it’s something we’re working on adding in a coming version.'*

ref: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2015/05/13/new-version-of-theme-creator-beta-available-now/